# whats the cron format for the following

Tags: cron, cronexpression

I need to run bash script at `2nd Sat of the month at 11pm`.I cant figure out its cronformat.

```
* * * * * *
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

This is the cronformat i found from the internet but i am new to this and i think this problem is kind of tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arg i waited so many days for the solution but not a single comment nor an answer. Anyway i think the answer is

```
0 23 8-14 * Sat
```

please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Run the cron every Saturday and only execute the script on the second Saturday:

```
* * * * 6 * test $(expr $(date +\%d) / 7) -eq 2 && <execute script here>
```